# Trying to a run a behave-script for automation testing but unable to set variable by "export app_id = 124322" and running it using getstatusoutput

Tags: python, automation, environment-variables, python-behave

Unable to add environment `variables("export app_id = 23342)` while running a python behave script as  using `subprocess` makes changes in a new child terminal.

Tried various ways to set the variables... it is not working..

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: This is a FAQ. Env vars are private to each process. A process cannot change the env vars of a different process; at least not without its cooperation. If you edit your question to include more context we might be able to suggest a solution. But as currently written the answer to your question is "It can't be done." P.S., Don't upvote your own question.

Comment: for example i have a created a file variables.sh in my python project folder of python behave. i tried running the file on the terminal using the code below..
payload_type = 'variables'
root_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath("Payloads"))
filePath = os.path.join(root_dir,'Payloads/'+ payload_type + '.sh')
context.response = getstatusoutput(" source " + filePath)

here variables file contains export APP_ID=1312 and few other varibales.